# How to sbt publish multi module project

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm a complete beginner in sbt/scala. I have a multi module sbt project that I build with `sbt assembly`, which creates jar files of my modules. When I tried `sbt module2/publish` I noticed the output jar file in my directory is super slim compared to the jar files created by sbt-assembly and its throwing error when I tried to run:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class 
com.example.module2.service.Server
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
```

What do I need to include in my build.sbt file to make sbt publishing possible?

```
my-proj
├── Build.scala
├── common
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
├── module1
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
├── module2
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
└── project
    ├── build.properties
    └── plugins.sbt
```

`Build.scala`

```
lazy val my_proj = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(common, module1, module2)

lazy val common = project

lazy val common = (project in file("commons"))

lazy val module1 = (project in file("module1"))
  .dependsOn(common, module2)

lazy val module1 = (project in file("module1"))
  .dependsOn(common)
```

`module1/build.sbt`

```
name := "module1"
version := "0.1"
organization := "com.example"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
val akkaVersion = "2.5.16"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Xcheckinit", "-encoding", "utf8")
fork := true

/** Dependencies */
resolvers ++= Seq("Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/",
  "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", new File("/tmp/my/artifactory")))

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library"    % scalaVersion
  , "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion
  , "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect"  % scalaVersion
  , "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
  
)
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "META-INF\\io.netty.versions.properties"             => MergeStrategy.first
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")           => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")       => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/")  => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case "reference.conf"                                     => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _                                                    => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: Well that is the expected behaviour, a published jar doesn't include any dependency.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez is there any way to make it include all the dependencies i.e. how to publish a fat jar with all its dependencies?

Comment: You already got the answer, just make sure that is what you really want. No library out there should do this for any reason; well you may shade a dependency or two if really necessary but still is not recommended. And if this is an application then it is weird that you want to distribute it through and artifact repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To publish a "fat" jar to a repository, you have to add the following to `build.sbt` of each sub-project you want to publish.

```scala
Compile / assembly / artifact ~= { art =>
  art.withClassifier(Some("fat"))
}

addArtifact(Compile / assembly / artifact, assembly).settings
```

Comment: Thank you, is there something I need to import? intellij is unable to resolve `withClassifier`

Comment: @PaCi No need to import anything. Make sure that you're using latest sbt and assembly plugin